# Extending pulses of a square wave signal

Tags: arduino-uno

My idea is to modify a diesel injection system to increase the fueling into the engine.

The signal to an injector is a series of 0.1-1.5ms pulses. I would like to analyse the pulses and then send out my own pulse to extend some of the injection pulses. I want to do this all in real time.

[image]

Is this possible on an arduino? I have never used one before so I'd like to know if it is possible and what product would be suitable.

Comment: What kind of diesel engine are you using? Have you looked at the injector waveform with an oscilloscope? If you have "Peak and Hold" style injectors: http://autoditex.com/page/peak-hold-injector-53-1.html, then you may have to replicate the "current limiting" phase of the injector "on time". Please edit your question and add some details about the diesel engine / injector you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming the calculations are not that time consuming.

The Arduino is 16 MHz, so this is in the us scale which is way within limits. I don't know how critical the rise and fall times are, but even that should be possible.

You need some additional circuitry though, because the Arduino itself cannot handle 12V signals. For the input, you need so called level shifting (from 12 V to 5 V), see [A-Quick-Guide-on-Logic-Level-Shifting](https://www.instructables.com/id/A-Quick-Guide-on-Logic-Level-Shifting/) for more explanation.

For the output, you need a 12 V signal (or use a voltage booster to 12V), and a transistor (and probably some resistors) that is connected to the Arduino for the signal and to the 12V and the diesel injection system for the 12V.

Comment: Wonderful I'll order a nano and take a look at it!

Comment: If it helps, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.